# On which column bloom filter is created - cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I want to understand on which column the bloom filter is built on. Does clustering key(s) also have bloom filter on ?
Also does clustering keys help to do faster search on clutering column

Answer (score 1):

> I want to understand on which column the bloom filter is built on. Does clustering key(s) also have bloom filter on ?

Partition key is used for updating/reading bloom filters. Clustering keys are not used for bloom filter. Think it this way, you fire a query without a clustering key, then how bloom filters will be used.

> Also does clustering keys help to do faster search on clutering column

Clustering column helps search in a way that they are sorted. Once you reach a partition using a partition key then its rows are sorted by clustering keys.

Answer (score 0):

Bloom filters are a probabilistic data structure that allows Cassandra to determine one of two possible states: - The data definitely does not exist in the given file, or - The data probably exists in the given file.

A bloom filter is the in-memory structure per SSTable, which helps Cassandra avoid a disk seek before the index is scanned for the data bloom filter. It is consulted and checked if the row is present. A bloom filter returns a Boolean advice irrespective of whether the data is in the SSTable or not. It can have a false-positive too.

There is no role of clustering column but playing over partition key.

You should refer below link for more understandings.

https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/bloom_filters.html